# How do I make use of Solr's MoreLikeThis feature with a MultiCore setup?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, morelikethis

So I have set up Solr with multiple cores using the MultiCore feature which works fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core_one/select/?q=Book
```

Works as expected and lists results.

Now all I want to do is send the same query to Solr with MoreLikeThis enabled:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core_one/select/?q=Book&mlt=true&mlt.fl=category
```

I get a *HTTP Status 500 - null java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.storedToIndexed*. The field for mlt.fl exists. The funny thing is if I query something that does not have any results Solr properly returns an empty result set.

So is this a bug or am I missing something?

This is the full stack trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - null java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.storedToIndexed(FieldType.java:360) at
org.apache.solr.handler.MoreLikeThisHandler$MoreLikeThisHelper.getMoreLikeThis(MoreLikeThisHandler.java:320) at
org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent.getMoreLikeThese(MoreLikeThisComponent.java:82) at
org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent.process(MoreLikeThisComponent.java:57) at
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:194) at
org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129) at
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1368) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356) at
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864) at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Solr. What's the full stack trace? What version are you using?

Comment: I tried with the latest release (3.4.0) and a previous one (3.2).

Comment: please format the stack trace, currently it shows in a single line.

Comment: do you have a unique field defined in your schema?

Comment: Yes, I have an unique field but I did not store it. After changing that everything works fine. Thank you @MauricioScheffer for pointing me in the right direction! What is the proper way to mark this question as answered?

Comment: Please report this to the Solr team: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MoreLikeThis requires a *stored* unique key.